# Concatenate two strings in an array using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want the output as the below string format using LINQ.

**["providerZip","providerType"]**

Can anyone please tell me, how to concatenate the two strings in an array using LINQ ?

Comment: Any code snippet? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `string.Join` is usually the best way to join an IEnumerable into a comma separated list. You don't need LINQ for that. If this is even your question.

Comment: `list[0] + list[1]`. I KNOW it's not LINQ, but I just couldn't resist

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
Contex.Tableuser.select{x=>new{Provider=x.ProviderZip+" "+x.ProviderType }}.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       string[] words = { "providerZip", "providerType" };
        var res = words.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
        Console.WriteLine(res);

    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error message as "cann't convert string to char

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
string[] str = { "providerZip", "providerType" };
var res = str.Aggregate((cur, nxt) => cur + ", " + nxt);
```

Comment: I am getting an error message as "cann't  convert string to char"

Comment: @AnandaPrasadJaisy:- Can you share your code? Without that it is hard to tell what you are doing?\

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to `Json Serialization` of a list of strings. That'd be the right way to go. For `Json` I've used `Json.NET` in my example below, you can use the .NET json serializer as well.

But, if really don't want that, you can still manually create that string using `string.Join` and a little `Linq`.

```
//input strings
var str = new List<string>{ "providerZip", "providerType" };

//with json serialization with Json.NET 
//using Newtonsoft.Json; <= install Json.Net NuGet package
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str); //=> ["providerZip","providerType"]

//with plain string manipulation + Linq
var outputString = "[" + string.Join(",", str.Select(s => "\"" + s + "\"")) + "]"; //=> ["providerZip","providerType"]
```